# In angularjs ngDialog.openConfirm dialog appears after whole function execution

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In angularjs I want to show confirm dialog on delete operation my code is below :

```
function deleteOperation(){
    var result;        
             ngDialog.openConfirm({
                    template:
                        '<p>Are you sure you want to delete selected conversation(s) ?</p>' +
                        '<div>' +
                          '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="closeThisDialog(0)">No&nbsp;' +
                          '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="confirm(1)">Yes' +
                        '</button></div>',
                    plain: true,
                    className: 'ngdialog-theme-default'
                }).then(function (value) {
                    result=true;
                }, function (value) {
                    result=false;
                });

            if (result == true) {
                // perform delete operation
 }
}
```

But dialog is displayed after whole function execution, so in if condition result variable get undefined value

Comment: You should execute the part `perform delete operation` inside the `then` callback where you set `result=true`. You could also call a function from there that performs the delete. This is the right place to do it

Comment: yes, you are right performing delete operation inside then callback works, thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Callback are asynchronous. So, you have to perform your operation in your success callback like this:

```
function deleteOperation(){     
             ngDialog.openConfirm({
                    template:
                        '<p>Are you sure you want to delete selected conversation(s) ?</p>' +
                        '<div>' +
                          '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="closeThisDialog(0)">No&nbsp;' +
                          '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="confirm(1)">Yes' +
                        '</button></div>',
                    plain: true,
                    className: 'ngdialog-theme-default'
                }).then(function (value) {
                    // perform delete operation
                }, function (value) {
                    //Do something 
                });
    }
```